# Got an e-mail with weird text and an .htm attachment. What does it do?

Tags: email-attachments

Here's the text from that e-mail (no subject)

```
31725714 65
TJBPYEW YBTLI UNILPW FPW J II
NSWKW LGKJQBS PVGVQX ZEWW WQUWFZ VT
```

Here's the code from the attachment I extracted with Notepad++:
https://pastebin.com/Fv9JPmu3
Being curious, I used Sandboxie (a sandboxing program) to open the file after saving it but nothing happened so I deleted the file and the sandbox contents.

I'm surprised Gmail didn't mark it as spam.
Since the e-mail includes a list of other recipients, I'm also sending them a warning not to open it, whatever it is.

Can you explain how to decode such e-mails?

Comment: This isn't a perfect duplicate of [Is this some kind of Bayesian poisoning?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/79757/42391) since the message content is slightly different (the payload is in an attachment and the gibberish isn't an arbitrary quote or word salad), but it's very close and I wrote the answer there to abstract to all cases of gibberish spam, including this one.

Answer (score 3):

The attachment contains a redirect. The redirect is base64 encoded, and leads to `hxxp://2021pro1.info/6TS7Z7bC?732316485`. That site appears to redirect to a bitcoin scam.

It's spam. Delete it and forget it. Life is too short to read spam.

Answer (score 0):

[Gibberish spam](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/12589/42391) comes in many forms.

This is one of them. This is likely a form of Bayesian poisoning, where they try to create enough novel tokens to water down your filter's ability to assign higher weights to spammy bits—which [doesn't really work](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/73181/42391#comment140520_73183).

This may also be a [hash buster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_buster), designed to mutate rapidly in order to evade detection.

See [my answer to this duplicate question](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/84676/42391).